# Model attribute "gets lost" in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to create simple form using spring and thymeleaf. This is my code:

```
@GetMapping("users/{id}")
public String editUser(@PathVariable long id,  Model model)
{
    User user = userService.findByID(id);
    Iterable<Role> roles= roleService.findAll();
    UserEditForm userEditForm = new UserEditForm(user);
    model.addAttribute("userEditForm", userEditForm);
    model.addAttribute("allRoles", roles);
    return "admin/userEdit";
}

@PostMapping("users/{id}")
public String updateUser(@PathVariable long id, @ModelAttribute UserEditForm userEditForm,
                         BindingResult bindingResult)
{
    userEditValidator.validate(userEditForm, bindingResult);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "admin/userEdit";
    }

    User user = new User(userEditForm);
    userService.save(user);
    return "redirect:/admin/users/{id}";
}
```

Almost everything works as exepected. The only thing that i don't understand is lack of `allRoles` modelAttribute (list is empty) when there are errors in form (and i get redirected back to correct them). I thought that maybe model object get reseted but userEditForm stays same as it was in Get request. Am i missing something? If not how can i correct it? Not sure if getting roles once again from db is good idea.

EDIT:

After advice from comment I came up with something like this (which works well):

```
@GetMapping("users/{id}")
public String editUser(@PathVariable long id,  Model model, HttpSession session)
{
    User user = userService.findByID(id);
    Iterable<Role> roles= roleService.findAll();
    UserEditForm userEditForm = new UserEditForm(user);
    model.addAttribute("userEditForm", userEditForm);
    model.addAttribute("allRoles", roles);
    session.setAttribute("allRoles", roles);
    return "admin/userEdit";
}

@PostMapping("users/{id}")
public String updateUser(@PathVariable long id, @ModelAttribute UserEditForm userEditForm,
                         BindingResult bindingResult, @SessionAttribute("allRoles") Iterable<Role> roles,
                         Model model, SessionStatus sessionStatus)
{
    userEditValidator.validate(userEditForm, bindingResult);


    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("allRoles", roles);
        return "admin/userEdit";
    }

    User user = new User(userEditForm);
    userService.save(user);
    sessionStatus.setComplete();
    return "redirect:/admin/users";
}
```

Just got some questions now. 
 1. Is this the best way to do this? Or should i query database whenever i need "roles"? Or maybe some different approach?
 2. How come `UserEditForm` object gets "automatically injected" into model (and i can use it in the view), while i need to invoke `model.addAttribute()` with `roles` in `updateUser` method?

Comment: The lifecycle of model attributes is the same as servlet request attributes, ie. one request-response cycle.

Comment: So any ideas how can i fix this "issue"?

Comment: Session attributes. Or pass them around from request to response to request.

Comment: My advice, you create a static list and fill the list at the project start.Then if you need all roles you can get all of them from static list.

Comment: @peterSchiza Since you have found a solution, you should post it as an answer and accept it. This will help the future users if they will have your same issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring - Model attributes after BindingResult with errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979148/spring-model-attributes-after-bindingresult-with-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After advice from comment I came up with something like this (which works well):

```
@GetMapping("users/{id}")
public String editUser(@PathVariable long id,  Model model, HttpSession session)
{
    User user = userService.findByID(id);
    Iterable<Role> roles= roleService.findAll();
    UserEditForm userEditForm = new UserEditForm(user);
    model.addAttribute("userEditForm", userEditForm);
    model.addAttribute("allRoles", roles);
    session.setAttribute("allRoles", roles);
    return "admin/userEdit";
}

@PostMapping("users/{id}")
public String updateUser(@PathVariable long id, @ModelAttribute UserEditForm userEditForm,
                         BindingResult bindingResult, @SessionAttribute("allRoles") Iterable<Role> roles,
                         Model model, SessionStatus sessionStatus)
{
    userEditValidator.validate(userEditForm, bindingResult);


    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("allRoles", roles);
        return "admin/userEdit";
    }

    User user = new User(userEditForm);
    userService.save(user);
    sessionStatus.setComplete();
    return "redirect:/admin/users";
}
```